# Does Ana's ult carry over to an ejecting DVa?

Tags: overwatch

Yesterday I was playing a game as Zarya. There was an Ana on our team, and though I was consistently the last one left alive in team fights (because Zarya never dies), I never saw the Ana use her ult. We ended up losing the game, at which point I inquired in chat as to whether or not the Ana ult had ever been used (strongly implying it should have been used on me). The Ana player responded that they *did* use their ult, but on the DVa, right before she exploded.

This made me wonder, if a big DVa is 'powered up', and her mech is killed, does the little DVa retain the power for the remaining time, or is it lost? And similarly, if a little DVa is nano-boosted and then calls in her mech, does she lose that boost?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No. Switching from mecha to mech-less (and vice versa) will cause the buff to be wasted.

This means you lose the buff in three ways:

- Mecha D.Va is powered up and then the mech is destroyed by an enemy
- Mecha D.Va is powered up and then she uses her ult (mech is destroyed)
- Mech-less D.Va is powered up and she calls her mech back

Source: I play Ana and it tilts me to no end when I boost a D.Va and she immediately decides to ult.

Comment: This is what I would have expected. Evidence gets votes.

Comment: In short: don't use an Ana ult on D.Va?

Comment: @Mast I don't know about that. D.Va does a lot of damage with her mech's cannons, *especially* in close quarters combat (which pretty much all capture points are). A boosted D.Va at full health does even more damage and is very hard to take down - she's got a lot of effective health, thanks to the damage-reducing properties of armor plus the damage reduction of the buff itself. The fact that she can keep putting out damage without stopping to reload makes her a better boost target than Roadhog in general (imo).

Answer (score 2):

**No.** If her mech is killed, or she uses her ultimate ability, Ana's Nano Boost is removed. The opposite also applies:  If she calls her mech while boosted, she does not keep the buff.